Problema con conexion con SQLite
Estoy Trabajando en un proyecto pequeño para registrar mantenimiento de maquinarias.
El problema es el siguiente: al hacer clic en "ver" en la lista de mantenimientos me abre el formulario del mantenimiento, pero en blanco, o sea no me trae los datos.
Sin embargo al hacer clic en el menú lateral en Mantenimientos y luego vuelvo a hacer clic en "ver" sobre el mismo registro si me trae los datos correctamente
Este es el codigo que se ejecuta para traer los datos
    const search = async () => {
    if (id === 'new') {
      setItem({ fecha: '', mantenimiento: '', kilometraje: '', tipo: '', funcionario: '' });
    } else {
      try {
        performSQLAction(async (db: SQLiteDBConnection | undefined) => {
          const respSelect = await db?.query(`SELECT * FROM mantenimientos WHERE id = ?`, [id]);
          if (respSelect && respSelect.values && respSelect.values.length > 0) {
            console.log("Encontré el registro con el ID:", id);
            setItem(respSelect.values[0]);
            console.log("Este es: " + respSelect.values[0].mantenimiento);
          } else {
            console.log("No se encontró ningún registro con el ID:", id);
            setItem({ fecha: '', mantenimiento: '', kilometraje: '', tipo: '', funcionario: ''});
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("ocurrio un error")
        alert((error as Error).message);
        setItem({ fecha: '', mantenimiento: '', kilometraje: '', tipo: '', funcionario: 
         ''});
      }
    }
  }

Este es el codigo que ejecuta la conexion con la base de datos
    const performSQLAction = async (
    action: (db: SQLiteDBConnection | undefined) => Promise<void>,
    cleanup?: () => Promise<void>
  ) => {
    try {
      await db.current?.open();
      await action(db.current);
    } catch (error) {
      alert((error as Error).message);
    } finally {
      try {
        (await db.current?.isDBOpen())?.result && (await db.current?.close());
        cleanup && (await cleanup());
      } catch {}
    }
  };

adjunto proyecto en GitHub si necesitan mas informacion: https://github.com/SearPy/appbarraconV1
Vista de la lista

Al hacer clic por primera vez en "ver" no trae los datos

Al hacer clic en el menu lateral en "Mantenimientos" y volver a clicar en "ver" trae los datos correctamente


El problema consiste en dos errores, el metodo search no tiene previsto el caso de que id sea indefinido por lo que al implementar
!id || id === 'new'

en el if ya se resuelve, el otro problema consiste en que useEffect se ejecuta al cargar la pagina, con el siguiente codigo nos aseguaramos que se rendericen todos los componentes de la pagina antes de ejecutar Search
useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     search();
   }, 0);
  }, [id]);


No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.
